# Hide/Blur Activity on opening another Activity over as pop-up Window(Not a Dialog Box) In Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am finding the solution from last few days, a solution will appreciate.
The scenario is:
There are two activities in my application 1. mainActivity 2.newActivity. On button click on mainActivity newActivity will be open as a pop-up window(not a dialog box). I want to hide/blur mainActivity when pop-up window(newActivity) is active and display mainActivity when pop-up(newActivity) activity close. how can I achieve this?

[image: On opening new activity looks like this]

Comment: Paste your related code also

Answer (score 0):

You can set background color code "#CC000000" of "newActivity" in xml layout.

Just use `android:background="#CC000000"` for your main Layout.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest putting an opaque Drawable or background (either black for darkening or white for fading) behind your popup.

This is not blurring the main activity but it highlits the foreground popup.

Just use a color like:

```
<color name="Translucent">#80000000</color>
```

Comment: Got the solution finally, Use following code in new activity in on Create() method.   
                                                          
 WindowManager.LayoutParams windowManager = getWindow().getAttributes();

        windowManager.dimAmount = 0.90f;
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);